# recursive function always returns null

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to retrieve a Category object from it's Id.
Category is hierarchical class that can contain other categories and posts.
My implementation is recursive:

```
public static AAbstarctCategory getCategory(ACategory category, String id) {
    if (id == category.id) {
        return category;

    }
    else if (category.categories.containsKey(id)) {
        return category.categories.get(id);

    }
    else if (category.posts.containsKey(id)) {
        return category.posts.get(id);

    }
    else {
        for (ACategory c : category.categories.getArray()) {
           getCategory(c,id);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem is that the function always returns null...
Suggestions please :)

Comment: debug and check the value of category and the value of id

Comment: add a return statement `return getCategory(c,id);`

Answer (score 4):

You are not using the value returned by the recursive call.

Change

```
    for (ACategory c : category.categories.getArray()) {
       getCategory(c,id);
    }
```

to

```
    for (ACategory c : category.categories.getArray()) {
       AAbstarctCategory cat = getCategory(c,id);
       if (cat != null)
           return cat;
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn´t it be better to save the value of `getCategory` into a value and check wheter it´s null and return if it´s not null. Otherwise the loop wouldn´t make sense.

Comment: It takes away the whole point of a recursive method it seems though lol

Comment: After reading the method, it doesn't make sense though. You should rewrite that array part.

Answer (score 0):

`return null;` at the end should be `return getCategory(c, id);` and then you need another base case that early returns null.